Replacing a Light Switch with a Smart Switch
I recently bought a Sonoff M5 Switchman 1 gang 1 way smart light switch off of amazon, the wiring required is straight forward, Neutral, Live and Load. However my existing wiring is not so easy to understand. I'm in the UK and this is a new build (~1-2 years ago now) however I have 2 load wires going into L1 in my old switch, 1 live wire going into COM and 3 neutral wires connected to each other in a plastic connector. I've tried adding an extra neutral wire to the connector and that hasn't worked (no sign of life in smart switch), I've tried using each neutral wire in the connector just to see if I could get the switch to work, no luck there. I've also tried the switch without the load wires to see if I could get it to turn on, still no luck. I know the switch is working as I wired it up to a plug and the indicator light lit up and went into pairing mode.
(By the way this is only switching one light, I have no idea why there are 2 pairs of wires)
Any help is appreciated!


This existing switch isn't a 3-way switch (I think you may call it a 2-way over there)?

Just a comment as I am in the US and not so familiar with UK terminology and practices. In the US on a non-smart single switch, there is no difference whatsoever between the two connections - e.g., if they are top and bottom you can make the top line and the bottom load or the top load and the bottom line - and whichever one is "line" (incoming always hot) often has a second wire providing always hot power to another switch or receptacle. It sounds like you have the same thing here, except that based on your description the expectation or normal practice would have L1 = load and COM = line

but that it was wired as if L1 = line and COM = load, so L1 has the extra wire. If that's the case, ignore the old switch labels and look at functionality instead to determine how to wire to the new smart switch.

@Huesmann Nope it's a one way switch. I have no idea what on earth is going on with the wiring. It's like this in all the rooms.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Just tried switching the wires round, and it worked! Thank you so much for saving me the headache.
